# sIFR text overpowering Thickbox modal background

Tags: z-index, thickbox, sifr3, silverstripe

I'm using both sIFR (v3) and a Thickbox on some pages of my website.  The Thickbox is a modal that shows a picture of a product. The problem is that when it is opened, the page's sIFR'ed heading does not get covered by the modal's background overlay. It must be a z-index issue, but I can't get it to sit behind the overlay.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try playing around with FireBug and the z-indices?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set the 'wmode' parameter of the sIFR embedded Flash to 'opaque'.

So just add this to your 'replace' call:

```
wmode: 'opaque'
```

e.g.

```
sIFR.replace(myFont, {
  selector: 'h1',
  wmode: 'opaque'
});
```